# php variable to javascript variable in html file

Tags: javascript, php

i have php file which has a variable  which is calculated from a given data. i want to pass this variable to a java script variable which is located in other  html file can some one help. i have tried like this but when i tried to display the value nothing comes. i want the variable to display countdown timer.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            require_once "getuser.php"; 
        ?>
        <script>
            var arrival_time = "<?php echo $arrival_time; ?>";
        </script>
    <body>
</html
```

Comment: what happens if you echo $arrival_time out to the screen outside of the javascript? Are you seeing your value?

Comment: no the value is not seen

Comment: Please try to provide a little more clarity on what you are asking.

Comment: i have a php variable on one file i want to pass this variable to a java script code which is inside an html file. the script is not external to the html file.

Comment: hrm... and what happens when you remove the double quotes which make that code a string?

Comment: the same result noting hapens

Comment: It should work. If it's not working, then `getuser.php` isn't setting `$arrival_time`. Can you post `getuser.php`?

Comment: i have removed some of the code to make it a little more clear

Comment: What does your page source look like? If it's `var arrival_time = "";` that's because `$arrival_time` is not set or empty. I guess it should be set in getuser.php? Can you post the code of this file? Your problem is not passing the value from PHP to JS but setting the variable value in the first place.

Comment: the getuser.php generates the arrival_time from the users input it looks like this not including the user input parts.   function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {}        //echo distance($latR, $lonR, $lat1, $lon1, "K") . " Miles<br>";
$tesfa1=distance($latR, $lonR, $lat2, $lon2, "K");
$tesfaA=distance($latA, $lonA, $lat2, $lon2, "K");
$distance=$tesfaA;
$arrival_time=($distance/$speed1)*60*60;

Comment: Assuming that getuser.php needs to process form input in order to correctly generate $arrival_time, and that the php file listed in your question is called test.php, then you should submit your form to test.php (set the form action to test.php), and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it the php value vs. a string like this:

```
var arrival_time = <?php echo $arrival_time; ?>;
```

Comment: the code<?php
            require_once "getuser.php"; 
        ?>
        <script>
            var arrival_time = <?php echo $arrival_time; ?>;
        </script>
        <h1>
      the value for number is:
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(arrival_time)
      </script>
    </h1>    the result is    the value for number is:

Comment: Also are you getting any php or js console errors returned?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is a good practice but this is my method of passing a php value to javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $arrivaltime; ?>" id="atime">

<script>

    var arrival_time = $("#atime").val();

</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is good practice, why would you create a DOM element and use jQuery if you could just write it directly into the variable?

Comment: @masterfloda oh im sorry didn't know. Im just a beginner too. Well i just want to share my method. Should i delete my answer?

Comment: @masterfloda Write directly in the variable you're meaning echoing the php in the script? It's worst than the example above, for sure.

There's nothing wrong to impute DOM elements to retrieve data with JS later, IMHO.

Comment: @calexandre yes, I mean echoing the value in the script. I don't really see any disadvantage of putting a string output in quotes and escape quotes in the string. like `var x = "<?php echo addcslashes($x, '"') ?.";`